# Exec onlyif registry value is not present

Tags: ruby, puppet

****EDIT****

I found a solution by playing around:

```
class add_route
{
        exec { "route_to_internal_network":
                command => "C:\Windows\System32\ROUTE.EXE add 192.168.5.254 mask 255.255.255.255 10.5.5.5 -p",
                unless => "C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\PersistentRoutes /f 192.168.5.254,255.255.252.0,10.5.5.5,1",
        }
}
```

I'll leave this post up in case anyone else is running into a similar problem

****EDIT****

---

I am trying to write a puppet manifest to add a persistent static route to some of my Windows host servers. So far, I am thinking of creating a class that does:

```
class add_route
{
    exec { "route_to_internal_network":
        command => "C:\Windows\System32\ROUTE.EXE add 192.168.5.254 mask 255.255.255.255 10.5.5.5 -p",
    }
}
```

However, this manifest will exec the command every time the puppet client checks in with the puppet master.

I was hoping to use `onlyif` in my class, but it seems a little confusing when trying to check for an absent registry value that contains my route.  Is this the best way to do this?  Any other ideas?

I imagine I need to do something like:

```
class add_route
{
    exec { "route_to_internal_network":
        command => "C:\Windows\System32\ROUTE.EXE add 192.168.5.254 mask 255.255.255.255 10.5.5.5 -p",
        onlyif => ???
    }
}
```

I was hoping my `onlyif` statement would match to

```
C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\PersistentRoutes /f '192.168.5.254,255.255.255.255,10.5.5.5,1'
```

If the result of the above command is:

> End of search: 0 match(es) found.

However, I think the `onlyif` is just looking for a return code, so whether or not this value is found, the command completes successfully.

Does anyone know how I could check for the absence of a registry value in a puppet manifest?

Comment: fyi https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-registry

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution by playing around:

```
class add_route
{
        exec { "route_to_internal_network":
                command => "C:\Windows\System32\ROUTE.EXE add 192.168.5.254 mask 255.255.255.255 10.5.5.5 -p",
                unless => "C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\PersistentRoutes /f 192.168.5.254,255.255.255.255,10.5.5.5,1",
        }
}
```

I'll leave this post up in case anyone else is running into a similar problem