# Telling Puppet to only run an install if registry key is not present

Tags: windows, automation, registry, installation, puppet

I have written manifest that installs an `.exe` and applies a hotfix to it every-time it installs on a new machine.

```
windowsinstaller { 'AppFabric install 1.1 install':     
  software_title  => 'AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server',
  software_path   => '/Microsoft/AppFabric1.1/WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe',
  install_options => ['/i','/SkipUpdates'],
}

windowsinstaller { 'AppFabric 1.1 HotFix install':  
  software_title  => 'Windows Server AppFabric v1.1 CU5 [KB2932678]',   
  software_path   => '/Microsoft/AppFabric1.1/AppFabric1.1-KB2932678-x64-ENU.exe',
  install_options => ['/q','/norestart'],   
  subscribe => Windowsinstaller['AppFabric install 1.1 install']
}

service { 'Remote Registry Service':
  name    => 'RemoteRegistry',
  ensure  => running,
  restart => true,
}
```

I am trying to get this install to run only if it's registry key is absent.

Using puppetlabs registry module you can manage keys, redirect them, and change the values.

**reference**: http://puppetlabs.com/blog/module-of-the-week-puppetlabs-registry-windows

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to simply check if the key is there, I can either delete it or make sure its present using `ensure => present` and `ensure => absent`.

As I can't put resources into variables I am finding it hard to use conditional statements, and as `present` and `absent` set the key instead of check it, I don't think I can use meta parameters with the `registry_key` resource.

I know that I can wrap everything in an if statement and use a custom fact but I have been told that this is not the right way to proceed.

If anyone has an example of where this has been done before either using this module or something else registered in the puppet forge or any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not aware of the "windowsinstaller" resource, anyway you shouldn't need to check registry if you use the native "package" resource: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#package-provider-windows

Comment: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.6/reference/resources_package_windows.html take not of the 'Package name must be the DisplayName' part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user manbart found the answer 7 months ago with this question

[Exec onlyif registry value is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462383/exec-onlyif-registry-value-is-not-present)

calling reg.exe to query the registry in an exec resource.